# MySQL Sending Data Slow - LEFT JOIN Query

Tags: mysql

I am currently performing a lookup against 2 tables using a `LEFT JOIN`. The transaction time is painfully slow, often ~10s. Please view the table/query/profile information below.

Table #1 (14k rows):

```
CREATE TABLE `price` (
`id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`PRICE_ID` varchar(255) COLLATE latin1_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`TYPE` varchar(255) COLLATE latin1_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`PRICING_REF` varchar(255) COLLATE latin1_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`STOCK_CODE` varchar(255) COLLATE latin1_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`CALC_METHOD` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
`CALC_VALUE` double DEFAULT NULL,
`STORED_PRICE` double DEFAULT NULL,
`ROUNDER_METHOD` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
`ROUNDER_DIRECTION` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
`ROUNDER_MULTIPLE_OF` double DEFAULT NULL,
`ROUNDER_ADJUSTMENT` double DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_ci;
```

Table #2 (18k rows):

```
CREATE TABLE `stock` (
 `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `STOCK_CODE` varchar(255) COLLATE latin1_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `DESCRIPTION` varchar(255) COLLATE latin1_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `SALES_PRICE` double DEFAULT NULL,
 `LAST_PURCHASE_PRICE` double DEFAULT NULL,
 `QTY_IN_STOCK` double DEFAULT NULL,
 `QTY_ON_ORDER` double DEFAULT NULL,
 `LAST_SALE_DATE` date DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_ci;
```

The query:

```
SELECT stock.*,price.stored_price,price.pricing_ref 
FROM stock 
    LEFT JOIN price ON stock.stock_code = price.stock_code 
    AND price.pricing_ref = '2HWE001' 
LIMIT 0,10
```

The profiler:

```
Detailed profile

Order   StateDocumentation  Time
1   Starting    102 µs
2   Checking Permissions    5 µs
3   Checking Permissions    3 µs
4   Opening Tables  36 µs
5   Init    35 µs
6   System Lock 11 µs
7   Optimizing  6 µs
8   Statistics  24 µs
9   Preparing   30 µs
10  Executing   2 µs
11  Sending Data    9.8 s
12  End 19 µs
13  Query End   8 µs
14  Closing Tables  16 µs
15  Freeing Items   67 µs
16  Cleaning Up 16 µs
```

I have enabled query_cache in MySQL but it's yielding little benefit. Can anyone shed some light/experience on this?

Comment: Do you have any indices on the `stock` and `price` tables?

Comment: This data is pulled via ODBC from an external database each night. There is no unique index set up on either table.

Comment: In your `LEFT JOIN`, each record from `stock` has to be compared against each record from `price`.  This is about 250K operations.  On top of this, there is no index.  I would advise you to use an index, if at all possible.

Comment: I've just added a unique index to each table, on the `id` column. It hasn't altered any transaction time.

Comment: The index on `id` doesn't help because the column is not used in the query. You should have indexes on the columns that appear in the `JOIN`, `WHERE` and `ORDER BY` clauses. Put [`EXPLAIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain.html) in front of your query to see what indexes are used and read the [documentation of `EXPLAIN`s output](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain-output.html) to find out how they are used.